# GET request sent even though POST method used - jQuery

Tags: jquery, post, flask, get

I'm trying to send a POST request to Flask with jQuery but it's showing up as a GET request. I've never had this sort of problem before, any idea as to why this could be happening?

### jQuery

```
system_data = {
    "system_name":"system_name",
    "system_description":"system_description",
    "system_tags":"system_tags",
    "system_chart":"system_chart",
    "system_model":"system_model",
    "system_page":"system_page"
    }

$.ajax({
    method:"POST",
    url:"/",
    data:system_data,
    success: function(response) {
        alert("success");
    }
});
```

And my IDE is telling me that this happened:

```
GET /?system_name=system_name&system_description=system_description&system_tags=system_tags&system_chart=system_chart&system_model=system_model&system_page=system_page HTTP/1.1" 200
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use `type` instead of `method`:

> An alias for `method`. You should use `type` if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0

[**`jQuery.ajax()`**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
    type    : "post",
    url     : "/",
    data    : system_data,
    success : function(response) {
        alert("success");
    }
});
```

Comment: wow, for some reason I thought that _method_ was also supported. Glad it was such an easy fix, thanks